Exclude dates not within specific ranges from a user-selected date range in node.js?
I have an array of multiple start and end date ranges and a user-selected start and end date range. I need to exclude the dates from the user-selected range that do not exist within the specified date ranges.
Date Ranges Array :-
const venueTimings = [
  {
    start_date: '2024-07-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    end_date: '2024-07-31T00:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    start_date: '2024-08-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    end_date: '2024-08-31T00:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    start_date: '2024-10-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    end_date: '2024-10-31T00:00:00.000Z'
  }
];


User-Selected Dates :-
const start_date = '2024-07-01T00:00:00.000Z';
const end_date = '2024-10-31T00:00:00.000Z';


I want to exclude dates from the start_date to end_date range that do not fall within any of the ranges in venueTimings.
Current Attempt :-
I have attempted the following code, but it doesn't fully achieve the desired result:-
if (moment(start_date) < moment(venueTiming.start_date)) {
  for (let d = moment(start_date); d.diff(venueTiming.start_date, 'days') <= 0; d.add(1, 'days')) {
    let date = d.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    excluded_dates.push({ date, reason: 'missing-venue-time' });
    blocked_dates.push(date);
  }
}
if (moment(venueTiming.end_date) < moment(end_date)) {
  for (let d = moment(venueTiming.end_date); d.isBefore(moment(end_date)); d.add(1, 'days')) {
    const date = d.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    if (d.format('dddd') === day) {
      excluded_dates.push({ date, reason: 'missing-venue-time' });
      blocked_dates.push(date);
    }
  }
}


Issue:-
The code above doesn't accurately exclude the dates outside the venueTimings ranges. How can I properly exclude the dates from the user-selected range (start_date to end_date) that are not within the venueTimings ranges?

You can easily iterate through venueTimings array and check for any date over-lapping with the user selected dates converted them to moment recognizable format. If so exclude the dates outside this overlap from the user-selected range.
Refer the code below for reference:


const venueTimings = [{
    start_date: '2024-07-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    end_date: '2024-07-31T00:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    start_date: '2024-08-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    end_date: '2024-08-31T00:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    start_date: '2024-10-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    end_date: '2024-10-31T00:00:00.000Z'
  }
];

const start_date = '2024-07-01T00:00:00.000Z';
const end_date = '2024-10-31T00:00:00.000Z';


const userStartDate = moment(start_date); // Convert user provided dates to moment recognizable format
const userEndDate = moment(end_date); // Convert user provided dates to moment recognizable format


function rangesOverlap(range1Start, range1End, range2Start, range2End) {
  return range1Start <= range2End && range1End >= range2Start; // Check if dates overlap on each other
}


let excludedDates = []; // All Excluded dates will be added excludedDates

venueTimings.forEach(venueTiming => {
  const venueStart = moment(venueTiming.start_date);
  const venueEnd = moment(venueTiming.end_date);
  if (rangesOverlap(userStartDate, userEndDate, venueStart, venueEnd)) {
    for (let d = moment.max(userStartDate, venueStart); d <= moment.min(userEndDate, venueEnd); d.add(1, 'day')) {
      excludedDates.push(d.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    }
  }
});

console.log('Excluded Dates:', JSON.stringify(excludedDates));
<html lang="en">

<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>

</html>



